# Sort SQL table with values from another table

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table(tblRequests) with the list of requests submitted by different users. The fields are:

```
RequestID, UserID, DateSubmitted, Status
```

I have another table(tblImportantUsers) with the list of important users. This table has only one field of UserID.

I want to display the requests submitted by the important users on top. I can achieve this using the below query:

```
select r.RequestID, r.UserID, r.DateSubmitted, r.Status
from tblRequests r left join tblImportantUsers u on r.UserID = u.UserID
order by u.UserID desc, r.DateSubmitted desc
```

However, I only want the active requests of important users to show on top. The inactive requests should be sorted according to the DateSubmitted field. I even tried the UNION method but it doesn't work either.

Is there any way I can achieve this without adding any extra columns in my requests table?

Thanks

Data in tblRequests:

```
RequestID   UserID   DateSubmitted   Status
1           205      3/12/2016       0
2           208      3/16/2016       1
3           203      3/17/2016       0
4           241      3/17/2016       1
5           210      3/18/2016       0
6           205      3/18/2016       1
7           203      3/19/2016       1
8           241      3/19/2016       1
```

Data in tblImportantUsers:

```
UserID
205
203
```

Required Result:

```
RequestID   UserID   DateSubmitted   Status
7           203      3/19/2016       1
6           205      3/18/2016       1
8           241      3/19/2016       1
5           210      3/18/2016       0
4           241      3/17/2016       1
3           203      3/17/2016       0
2           208      3/16/2016       1
1           205      3/12/2016       0
```

Comment: Is `status` what monitors if the request is active or not?

Comment: Yes, active requests have status 1, inactive requests have 0

Comment: sample data and the desired output would help us understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works on redshift:

```
   select
       a.requestid
     , a.userid
     , a.datesubmitted
     , a.status
   from
     tblrequests a 
     left join tblimportantusers b on (a.userid = b.userid)
   order by
     (case when status = 1 and b.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
     , date submitted desc
     , userid desc
```

Comment: This is perfect. It does exactly what I wanted and I don't have to use union. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select RequestID, UserID, DateSubmitted, Status
from (
select r.RequestID, r.UserID, r.DateSubmitted, r.Status, 1 as ind
from tblRequests r inner join tblImportantUsers u on r.UserID = u.UserID
order by r.status desc, r.DateSubmitted desc

union all

select r.RequestID, r.UserID, r.DateSubmitted, r.Status, 0 as ind
from tblRequests r left outer join tblImportantUsers u on r.UserID =    u.UserID
where u.UserID is null
order by r.status desc, r.DateSubmitted desc)

order by ind desc, DateSubmitted desc, userID
```

Doing an inner join and a left OUTER join

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my mistake, I am actually using left join.

Comment: @S.Arzoo, feel free to accept if this solves your problem.

Comment: Actually it didn't, when I run the query with left join, it doesn't show the requests by important users on top